# Python search genes for barcode sequences and output matches into their corresponding files

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics

I am fairly new to python and have gotten a bit stuck. Basically what I am trying to do is use my barcode sequences to search and match to different gene sequences. I need each to create a fastq file named after each barcode sequence and output only the genes that match that barcode into the corresponding file.

My script will output only a few barcode sequence files but will copy the entire genome into the file. I am not sure how to only output the matches. My file 'clinical_data.txt' contains information about the barcode sequences and the barcode itself. My file 'sequences.fastq' is what contains the list of genes I am searching.

```
#I wasn't sure how to directly search the barcode sequences from 'clinical_data' so I outputted them to their own file

text_strings = [] 
with open('clinical_data.txt') as ff:
    ss = ff.readlines() 
for s in ss:
    text_strings.append(s.split('\t')[-1]) 
with open('out_file.txt', 'w') as outf:
    outf.write('\n'.join(text_strings))

def matches_barcode(sequence, barcodes):
  for bc in barcodes:
    if sequence.startswith(bc):
      return True
  return False
#Here I attempt to match the barcodes to the genes and create the new file at the same time
barcodes = []
with open('out_file.txt', 'r') as barcodefile:
    for barcode in barcodefile:
        barcodes.append(barcode.strip())
        with open('sequences.fastq', 'r') as seqfile:
            for sequence in seqfile:
                if matches_barcode(sequence.strip(), barcodes):
                    for line in barcodes:
                        with open(line + '.fastq', 'w') as f:
                            f.write(line)
                            f.writelines(sequence)
```

I definitely feel like there is a better way to go about doing this than what I have so far. It seems very slow and doesn't work the way I want it to. If someone would be able to point me in the direction of generally what I should be doing it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You question is quite vague and we don't know which is the issue, but I think I can give you some help.

It looks like you are overcomplicating the procedure. The whole code where you read the barcodes and writes them to a file could be simplified as:

```
with open("clinical_data.txt", encoding="UTF-8") as ff, open(
    "out_file.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8"
) as outf:
    for line in ff:
        print(line.split("\t")[-1], file=outf)
```

Reading everything into memory at once can lead easily to memory issues. The same for the join in the output: you can write the different lines one by one instead of generating an in-memory copy of the file to write. Processing line by line is far more suitable in memory load. Also, it is a good practice to define the file encoding and not rely on the defaults, as these could change.

The `matches_barcode` method is also orthopedic. You should never have a `return True` or `return False`. You are doing some boolean operations to know if it must be true or false, just return them. My re-implementation for that method would be:

```
def matches_barcode(sequence, barcodes):
    return any(sequence.startswith(bc) for bc in barcodes)
```

In any case, for your main goal, I think that these two pieces of code are useless. You don't need to create a file to keep the barcodes, you can just extract them from the original file and only keep the data neded in memory. And you don't need to know if the sequence matches some barcode, but which one matched.

To get the list of barcodes from the original file, I woudl use a method like:

```
def get_barcodes(input_file):
    with open(input_file, encoding="UTF-8") as f_in:
        barcodes_set = {line.split("\t")[-1].strip() for line in f_in}

    return barcodes_set
```

And for the search itself, I would start by reading the barcodes with the previous function. Then I would generate a dictionary from barcodes to files to keep the different files related to each barcode open until the end. I would create those files on demand. Then, I would traverse the sequences file and get the matching barcodes. In case there is some matching barcode, I will write the sequences to the needed file.

```
barcodes = get_barcodes("clinical_data.txt")
barcode_files = {}
with open("sequences.fastq", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as seqfile:
    try:
        for sequence in seqfile:
            matching_barcodes = {
                matching for matching in barcodes if sequence.startswith(matching)
            }
            for the_barcode in matching_barcodes:
                if not barcode_files[the_barcode]:
                    barcode_files[the_barcode] = open(
                        the_barcode, "w", encoding="UTF-8"
                    )
                print(sequence, file=barcode_files[the_barcode])
    finally:
        for barcode_file in barcode_files.values():
            barcode_file.close()
```

I would pre-create all the files at the beginning if I want to have them all despite they can be empty. My approach has been to create them only on demand, which cause me to close them in the `finally` block of the `try`. Otherwise, they could had been open in a context manager and forget about closing them.

This code is based on your attempt, but I see potential issues. You don't say anything about the formats of your files, but you said something about fastq files. You are processing your input as a list of sequences (and not fastq records), and the output is also a list of sequences (and not fastq records). If you are really working with fastq files you will have to adapt the code to that requirement.